# Is there a "registry rebuild" command?

Tags: drush

I just did a fresh Drush installation, and now I have version 8.1.15.

When I run `drush rr`, I get the following error message.

> The drush command 'rr' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.

Even after running `drush cache-clear`, I still get that `rr` is not a known command.

Is this still available in Drush 8?

Comment: Use `drush cr`.

Comment: I think CR is simply drush 8 version of "cc all", isn't it?

Comment: `cc all` doesn't exist in 8. `cr` is cache-rebuild and will do all of that including rebuild caches related to class discovery and annotations etc.

Comment: Note liquidcms is asking for drush 8 not drupal 8

Comment: Could you specify the Drupal version you are using? Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 require different drush commands.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild

The documentation is there:

> How To Use Registry Rebuild With Drush
>
> This is the preferred technique, and it should work with multisite installs.
>
> You can just `drush @none dl registry_rebuild-7.x` and drush will download it into your .drush folder. (Alternately, you can obtain the package another way and copy the folder into .drush yourself.)
>
> Make a backup of your database.
>
> Clear Drush own cache with `drush cc drush`
>
> On a multisite install, either use correct drush alias, or cd into the site you're rebuilding, as in cd sites/mymultisite
>
> Run `drush rr` or `drush @sitename rr` for soft rebuild (default), or:
>       To force aggressive rebuild from scratch run `drush @sitename rr --fire-bazooka`

Comment: Question is regarding Drush 8. I think your answer only applies to Drush 7 and lower.

Comment: I'm using drush 8 with drupal 7 projects and the above is working.

Answer (score 0):

That command (drush rr) is currently only for Drupal 7.

It does not matter what version of Drush you use since it is enabled for Drush via a module.

The module that enables that command does not work as of now for newer versions of Drupal.

--> Module link is https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild as stated in the answer by @FLY